# Rails - How to associate a "Shop" with more than one "Mall" at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a simple rails app which acts as a directory of all Malls in Kuwait and Shops within that mall. I created a Shop model and Mall model and made the following association:-

```
class Shop
has_many_and_belongs_to :malls

class Mall
has_many :shops
```

As the same shop can exist in more than one mall, I would like a way for me to link a shop with more than one mall at the same time. How can I make it so that a shop automatically appears under many different malls when I go to that malls show page, without having to individually create the same shop each time for each mall. So in other words I need to be able to choose which malls the shop belongs to while im creating a new shop, and then have that shop appear in the malls that I previously specified.

**Update:**
Explain assigning the shop to a particular mall in the creation process. For example when I create a new shop, how do I then specify that it belongs to Mall A and Mall B but not Mall C, and then have them appear in the corresponding Malls show page?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a HABTM association to handle this,

```
   class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :malls
   end

   class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
   end
```

Create migrations for Shop and Mall table, you need to have a migration to create a table which works as a join between shop and mall. It should contain mall_id and shop_id as attributes.

```
rails g migration create_mall_shops
```

Update for controller code:

```
 shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
 mall = Mall.find(params[:mall_id])
 shop.malls << mall
```

shop.malls will give you an array of malls related to shop.
Now, coming back as you expect, in shop.malls array, push only mall object A and B. So mall C will never be related to shop

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. So I know now how to assign the associations, but Im still non the wiser as to how I then go about assigning the shop to a particular mall in the creation process. For example when I create a new shop, how do I then specify that it belongs to Mall A and Mall B but not Mall C, and then have them appear in the corresponding Malls show page?

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and let you know. Just to be sure, the controller code you provided should go in the create action of the shop controller?

Comment: yes, but there is not such rule just a convention. I would also suggest you to read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: im sorry, im still quite confused as to how to make this work. I have made the associations, created the join table with mall_id and shop_id, but i dont quite understand what to do next with the controller code and then how to make it so that i can edit the relationship between a shop and a mall from the shop form itself. im sorry if this should be obvious but im new to rails and coding in general so its not so obvious to me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89055/discussion-between-bijendra-and-rashed-al-julaibi).